# SoftLayer Event_Log object filter ignoring specified timezone

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to query the SoftLayer audit log (SoftLayer_Event_Log) data.  I am applying an object filter based on datestamps, but the filter ignores timezone aware datestamps.

Code snippets are from Python.

Object Filter:

```
{u'eventCreateDate': {u'operation' : u'betweenDate',
                      u'options'   : 
                          [
                              {u'name'  : u'startDate',
                               u'value' : ['2016-02-25T19:21:53.796725+00:00']},
                              {u'name'  : u'endDate',
                               u'value' : ['2016-02-25T20:13:40.507255+00:00']}
                          ]
                     }
}
```

Result:

```
{'accountId'       : 654321,
 'eventCreateDate' : '2016-02-25T19:39:10.794659-06:00',
 'eventName'       : 'Login Successful',
 'ipAddress'       : '5.6.7.8',
 'label'           : 'username',
 'objectId'        : 123456,
 'objectName'      : 'User',
 'traceId'         : 'redacted',
 'userId'          : 123456,
 'userType'        : 'CUSTOMER',
 'username'        : 'username'}
{'accountId'       : 654321,
 'eventCreateDate' : '2016-02-25T19:39:01.567608-06:00',
 'eventName'       : 'Login Failed',
 'ipAddress'       : '1.2.3.4',
 'label'           : 'username',
 'objectId'        : 123456,
 'objectName'      : 'User',
 'traceId'         : 'redacted',
 'userId'          : '',
 'userType'        : 'SYSTEM'}
...etc...
```

The result data is definitely within the time specification, but not within the timezone specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object filter ignores the timezones, it only filters the date stored in the database. If am not wrong the date in the database is stored in Dallas timezone, so you have to change your start and  end date taking in account the difference between the timezone of your user and the timezone stored in the database.

Comment: The output of dates from the SoftLayer API do appear to be timezone aware, though.  You may change the timezone in the SoftLayer_User_Customer profile of the API user and the dates are converted to the timezone specified in the profile.

Does this mean that all input timestamps are expected to be CST or the timezone specified in the user profile?

Comment: yep that is correct the timezone is converted to your time zone when the data is displayed. but when the filter is executed it works over the data stored in the database and it is stored in dallas timezone.

Comment: Okay, makes sense.  Last question, is this true for all object types, or only for SoftLayer_Event_Log?